# What is correct reading for 舞桜

Tags: kanji, readings, names

What is the correct reading of word 舞桜? I found some pages, where they state, that it's one of variants of female name read as 「まお」, in this form meaning "dancing cherry blossom", but I checked in some dictionaries (e. g. [jisho.org](http://jisho.org)) and I couldn't find anything about this. So how is it?

P. S. I'm relatively new to the japanese language, so if you can refer me to other sources, I will be glad. Thank you.

Comment: If it's someone's name, you should probably ask them how it's read.  Or if it's in an anime/manga, usually it's explained somewhere how it is read, like in the introduction pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

舞桜 could indeed be a given name for girls. It's listed as such in jisho.org: you should search for `舞桜 #names`. jisho.org gives lots of readings; I would have guessed まお, but the other readings are probably someone's name, too.

> まう 【舞桜】
>   Female given name
>   1. Mau
>
> まよ 【舞桜】
>   Female given name
>   1. Mayo
>
> まおう 【舞桜】
>   Female given name
>   1. Maou
>
> まお 【舞桜】
>   Female given name
>   1. Mao
>
> まいさくら 【舞桜】
>   Female given name
>   1. Maisakura
>
> まいざくら 【舞桜】
>   Female given name
>   1. Maizakura
>
> まあさ 【舞桜】
>   Female given name
>   1. Maasa

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. I didn't know about the #name option. That's very useful.

Comment: @VaclavPelc It searches ENAMDICT, which is a file containing a very large number of names.  Many of them are uncommon, so please keep that in mind when searching.